# Assign parent child catgory using functions.php wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a gravity form and when a user submits a post its is added to back end.

The issue is I want to assign a parent child relation for the post that was created.

I was using a hook to get it done using functions.php

And I was using

```
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, array( 1 ,2) );
```

Let us assume the categories are "Bath" and "4 Baths"

This is working but the categories are assigned as 2 categories i.e "Bath" as one and "4 Baths" as another. I want to work in such a way that "Bath" will be parent category and "4 Baths" would be child category.

Would be great if someone can help me with same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this out, we need to use wp_set_post_terms()

```
 wp_set_post_terms( 244, 36, store_filter ,true);
 wp_set_post_terms( 244, 39, store_filter ,true);
```

Here 244 is post id, 36 is child category, store_filer is taxonomy and true indicates append to existing taxonomy.